# Excel - mileage car maintenance schedule

Tags: excel

I have a car that has specific maintenance at every 5k and 18k miles. I need a formula that calculates the maintenance sequence on this step. So for example:

```
5.000 miles
10.000 miles
15.000 miles
18.000 miles
20.000 miles
25.000 miles
30.000 miles
35.000 miles
36.000 miles
40.000 miles
45.000 miles
50.000 miles
54.000 miles
55.000 miles
60.000 miles
65.000 miles
70.000 miles
72.000 miles

.
.
.
```

and so on. How do I do it?

Comment: 5k, 10k, select, pull down; 18k, 36k, select, pull down; copy under each other; remove duplicates; sort. 1 minute tops. Or you can try to write a formula, actually pretty interesting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It will serve but unfortunately I'm building a worksheet so it needs to work with any car with any specific intervals. The 5k and 18k was just an example, that's why I wanted a formula instead of a fixed interval. For example: a car that has maintenance intervals at every 5k, 6k and 20k and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I am only answering this because it was a good puzzle.

The best method is the one stated by vacip in his comment.

"5k, 10k, select, pull down; 18k, 36k, select, pull down; copy under each other; remove duplicates; sort. 1 minute tops."

But this formula will do what you want:

```
=IF(5000*(INT(A1/5000)+1)>18000*(INT(A1/18000)+1),18000*(INT(A1/18000)+1),5000*(INT(A1/5000)+1))
```

Put `5000` in A1.

In A2 put the formula.  Then copy drag down.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your formula. I would like to enhance it further by making it compatible with any car interval, for example, every 5k, 6k and 20k, according to user input. But this is a baseline and I'll work to improve it. Thanks again!

Comment: @HélioShimojo please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  to make it dynamic you can set all the hard coded values to cells in which you type the values.

Comment: Done! I'm a recent member and I got this message when voted up: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.". Sorry!

Comment: @HélioShimojo you can click the check mark by the answer it does not matter the rep points.